# A Blank Line Appears Between Consecutive Index Entries When Top Entry Extends Too Far to the Right

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, makeindex, vertical-spacing, idxlayout

Consider the MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}

\newcommand{\beforeheadspace}{.7ex}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\beforesubheadspace}{.4ex}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\renewcommand\subitem{\vspace*{\beforeheadspace}\par\hangindent 40pt \hspace*{20pt}} % added <<<<<
\renewcommand\subsubitem{\vspace*{\beforesubheadspace}\par\hangindent 40pt \hspace*{30pt}} % added <<<<<

\begin{document}
\large
    
Some words.\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}!1@ \textbf{\color{red}{Subheading}}! This sentence is the first entry.}
\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}!2@ \textbf{\color{red}{Subheading}}! This sentence of anoher set of words -- illustrates the effect.}
\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}!3@ \textbf{\color{red}{Subheading}}! These words comprise the third entry.}
               
\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which produces the Index:

[image]

In the code, I have added some additional vertical space between the subheadings and entries as follows:

```
\newcommand{\beforeheadspace}{.7ex}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\beforesubheadspace}{.4ex}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\renewcommand\subitem{\vspace*{\beforeheadspace}\par\hangindent 40pt \hspace*{20pt}} % added <<<<<
\renewcommand\subsubitem{\vspace*{\beforesubheadspace}\par\hangindent 40pt \hspace*{30pt}} % added <<<<<
```

But, this seems to be causing the problem, for when I remove these lines and run the code, the undesirable blank line disappears.

QUESTION: How may I add the aforesaid additional vertical space between the subheadings and entries, while avoiding the occasional blank line from appearing when an entry extends too far to the right.

*Remark:* I do not ever recall encountering the blank line problem when I do not include the `newcommand` and `renewcommand` code---such index entries either stay on one line or break onto the next with at least the page number displayed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you observe is some blank stuff at the end of the long line that wraps to the next line (resulting in an apparently empty line), before `\par` starts a new paragraph.

You can either switch `\vspace*` and `\par`:

```
\renewcommand\subitem{\par\vspace*{\beforeheadspace}\hangindent 40pt \hspace*{20pt}}
```

Or you can remove the optional trailing stuff yourself by `\unskip`:

```
\renewcommand\subitem{\unskip\vspace*{\beforeheadspace}\par\hangindent 40pt \hspace*{20pt}}
```

Comment: (I think an extra closing brace is needed in the first `renewcomand`.) Both suggestions work nicely.  Many thanks.

Comment: @mlchristians Thanks for the note, I corrected the typo